# Applescript / Javascript : select menu

Tags: applescript, javascript

I'm filling a webpage using Applescript / Javascript,

one of them is a dropdown menu, which I fill with this code :

```
document.querySelector('select#reasonPopUpButton').value = '18';
```

the issue is the index change time to time.

Can I select the good menu using the title instead of the index?

Here what I tried so far :

```
tell application "Safari"
    do JavaScript "document.querySelector('select#reasonPopUpButton').value = 'Unauthorized purchase';" in current tab of window 1

end tell
```

Comment: I'd try using the `.innerText` or `.innerHTML` _property_, e.g. `document.querySelector('select#reasonPopUpButton').innerText = "Unauthorized purchase"; ...`

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I tried document.querySelector('select#reasonPopUpButton').innerText = 'Unauthorized purchase'; but then the dropdown menu become small with no value at all inside

Comment: How about with `.innerHTML` instead, did you get the same results? Can you provide the actual URL of the page the dropdown menu is on?

Comment: same, that remove all the option, only the index (.value = '18';) seems to work. worst  case I'll leave it like this, thank you anyway

Comment: Can you provide the actual URL of the page the dropdown menu is on?

Answer (score 1):

You can filter the list of options for one with the text you're looking for, then select that one. This can be achieved with the following JavaScript:

```
Array.from(document.querySelector('select#reasonPopUpButton').children)
  .find(el => el.textContent == "Unauthorized purchase")
  .selected = true;
```